# cumcount() None

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have a new columnen ( not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car ) that counts the None values in my Dataframe up until the row I am in, groupted by x, sorted by x and y.

```
import pandas as pd
x_start = 1
y_start = 1
size_city = 10

cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.repeat(np.arange(x_start,x_start+size_city),size_city),
                    'y': np.tile(np.arange(y_start,y_start+size_city),size_city),
                     'pizza_ordered' : np.repeat([None,None,1,6,3,7,5,None,8,9,0,None,None,None,4,None,11,12,14,15],5)})
```

The first 4 columns is what I have, and the 5th is the one I want.

```
    x   y     pizza_ordered                 not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car
0   1   1          None                                      0
1   1   2          None                                      1
2   1   3             1                                      2
3   1   4             2                                      2
4   1   5             1                                      2
5   1   6             1                                      2
6   1   7             1                                      2
7   1   8          None                                      2
8   1   9             1                                      3
9   1  10             4                                      3
10  2   1             1                                      0
11  2   2          None                                      0
12  2   3          None                                      1
13  2   4          None                                      2
14  2   5             4                                      3
15  2   6          None                                      3
16  2   7             5                                      4
17  2   8             3                                      4
18  2   9             1                                      4
19  2  10             1                                      4
```

This is what I have tried, but it does not work.

```
    cars = cars.sort_values(['x', 'y'])
    cars['not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car'] = cars.where(cars['pizza_ordered'].isnull()).groupby(['x']).cumcount().add(1)
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match `cumsum` of `NaN` values. Because it should start with 1 not 0, right?

Comment: Do you want this: `cars['not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car'] = cars['pizza_ordered'].isnull().cumsum()
`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
cars["not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car"] = cars.groupby("x")[
    "pizza_ordered"
].transform(lambda x: x.isna().cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int
    ))
print(cars)
```

Prints:

```
     x   y pizza_ordered  not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car
0    1   1          None                                      0
1    1   2          None                                      1
2    1   3          None                                      2
3    1   4          None                                      3
4    1   5          None                                      4
5    1   6          None                                      5
6    1   7          None                                      6
7    1   8          None                                      7
8    1   9          None                                      8
9    1  10          None                                      9
10   2   1             1                                      0
11   2   2             1                                      0
12   2   3             1                                      0
13   2   4             1                                      0
14   2   5             1                                      0
15   2   6             6                                      0
16   2   7             6                                      0
17   2   8             6                                      0
18   2   9             6                                      0
19   2  10             6                                      0
20   3   1             3                                      0
21   3   2             3                                      0
22   3   3             3                                      0
23   3   4             3                                      0
24   3   5             3                                      0
25   3   6             7                                      0
26   3   7             7                                      0
27   3   8             7                                      0
28   3   9             7                                      0
29   3  10             7                                      0
30   4   1             5                                      0
31   4   2             5                                      0
32   4   3             5                                      0
33   4   4             5                                      0
34   4   5             5                                      0
35   4   6          None                                      0
36   4   7          None                                      1
37   4   8          None                                      2
38   4   9          None                                      3
39   4  10          None                                      4
40   5   1             8                                      0
41   5   2             8                                      0
42   5   3             8                                      0
43   5   4             8                                      0
44   5   5             8                                      0
45   5   6             9                                      0
46   5   7             9                                      0
47   5   8             9                                      0
48   5   9             9                                      0
49   5  10             9                                      0
50   6   1             0                                      0
51   6   2             0                                      0
52   6   3             0                                      0
53   6   4             0                                      0
54   6   5             0                                      0
55   6   6          None                                      0
56   6   7          None                                      1
57   6   8          None                                      2
58   6   9          None                                      3
59   6  10          None                                      4
60   7   1          None                                      0
61   7   2          None                                      1
62   7   3          None                                      2
63   7   4          None                                      3
64   7   5          None                                      4
65   7   6          None                                      5
66   7   7          None                                      6
67   7   8          None                                      7
68   7   9          None                                      8
69   7  10          None                                      9
70   8   1             4                                      0
71   8   2             4                                      0
72   8   3             4                                      0
73   8   4             4                                      0
74   8   5             4                                      0
75   8   6          None                                      0
76   8   7          None                                      1
77   8   8          None                                      2
78   8   9          None                                      3
79   8  10          None                                      4
80   9   1            11                                      0
81   9   2            11                                      0
82   9   3            11                                      0
83   9   4            11                                      0
84   9   5            11                                      0
85   9   6            12                                      0
86   9   7            12                                      0
87   9   8            12                                      0
88   9   9            12                                      0
89   9  10            12                                      0
90  10   1            14                                      0
91  10   2            14                                      0
92  10   3            14                                      0
93  10   4            14                                      0
94  10   5            14                                      0
95  10   6            15                                      0
96  10   7            15                                      0
97  10   8            15                                      0
98  10   9            15                                      0
99  10  10            15                                      0
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

cars['not_ordered_in_STREET_x_before_my_car'] = pd.isnull(cars['pizza_ordered']).cumsum()